# Importing LibGDX project in Eclipse: Could not resolve: project :core

Tags: eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I'm working in a project with someone else, so we need to use the same project file. But I get this notification everytime I try to import his project (which already has code written on it). It is not only missing the whole core folder, but it is also missing pretty much every class.
We have the same JDK(12.0.2), Gradle version (5.4.1) and plugins installed, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I couldn't find anyone else with this same problem.

> Task :nothing UP-TO-DATE
> Could not resolve: project :core

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AFTq.png) is how the project looks when imported and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zq7vr.png) is how my normal projects look.

I should add I have no troubles with projects created by myself right now, and it took me a REALLY long time to get that to work, so I wouldn't like to mess with the JDK or the Gradle version if it's possible.

EDIT: Someone told me to add the build.gradle file, so here it is:

```
    buildscript {
    

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        

    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "JUEGO"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.10'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.8'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I remember the days years ago of fighting build issues like these for hours at a time. It all ended when I switched to IntelliJ IDEA, which seems to play a lot nicer with Gradle.

Comment: We'll have to see your build.gradle files to be able to provide any input, but I personally am no longer familiar with Gradle projects in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, I just added the files. And yes, setting up a Gradle project in Eclipse is a nightmare, I wish I had known about IntellijIDEA before.